# ArangoSearch on JSONarray objects

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am trying to use arango search on nested json array object in a view. it works fine on single non array json fields. but craps out when search is on a json array.

Sample JSON object

```
{
    "_key": "xx1sdas",
    "itemId": "xx1",
    "parent": [{
        "childId": "t1",
        "childName": "kai"
    }, {
        "childId": "t2",
        "childName": "tom"
    }]
}
```

The error message is not much helpful too
Query: AQL: not implemented: Unable to evaluate loop variable 'item' as a part of ArangoSearch noncompliant expression '_EXPANSION(_ITERATOR($0.parent,$2),$2.childName,) == "tom"' (while executing)

```
FOR item IN itemsView
  SEARCH ANALYZER(item.parent[*].childName IN TOKENS('tom', 'text_en'), 'text_en')
  SORT BM25(item) DESC 
  LIMIT 10 
RETURN item
```

Answer (score 3):

figured out that in arangosearch, there is no need to expand jsonarray. the below query worked for me.

```
FOR item IN iView
  SEARCH ANALYZER(item.parent.childName IN TOKENS('tom', 'text_en'), 'text_en')
  SORT BM25(item) DESC 
  LIMIT 10 
RETURN item
```

reference: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/9616